# Why is my SD card not empty when I deleted all items?

Tags: mac, memory, sd-card

I am using a GoPro 5 and Mac Book Pro with macOS HighSierra 10.13.6.

Since the SD card from my GoPro was nearly full, I saved all my data and deleted ALL files using right click and delete.

But for some reason, the card is still shows 46GB used. 
The strange thing is, that I moved two videos, roughly 1GB, to another USB flash drive and as expected it showed 1GB less free capacity on the USB. But when I deleted the  files on my USB flash drive the 1GB was still used. So the problem isn't the SD card but the files.

I know I could format everything... but I want to understand the reason. Furthermore I copied 20 GB of pictures from the SD to my Mac. I worry that the same problem occurs here too. So if you/we can't figure out why, I lost 20GB until I format my Mac.

My idea would be to `cd` into the folder and delete all hidden files? But why do I have this problem?

Here is what I see via `ls -al`:

```
total 4096
drwxrwxrwx  1 hoffab  staff   131072 31 Dez  1979 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root    wheel      192 23 Aug 17:57 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 hoffab  staff   131072  1 Sep  2017 .Trashes
drwxrwxrwx  1 hoffab  staff   131072  1 Jan  2012 .android_secure
drwxrwxrwx  1 hoffab  staff   131072 23 Aug 13:59 .fseventsd
drwxrwxrwx  1 hoffab  staff   131072 26 Jul  2017 System Volume Information
-rwxrwxrwx  1 hoffab  staff        4  3 Jun  2017 _disk_id.pod
-rwxrwxrwx  1 hoffab  staff  1194517 13 Aug 15:44 mdb.bk
```

and `du -h`:

```
256K    ./.fseventsd
384K    ./System Volume Information
9,6G    ./.Trashes/502/105GOPRO
 13G    ./.Trashes/502/104GOPRO
7,7G    ./.Trashes/502/103GOPRO
6,1G    ./.Trashes/502/102GOPRO
6,5G    ./.Trashes/502/101GOPRO
128K    ./.Trashes/502/100GOPRO
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.samsung.android.slinkcloud/files
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.samsung.android.slinkcloud/cache
384K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.samsung.android.slinkcloud
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.visionobjects.resourcemanager/files
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.visionobjects.resourcemanager
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.skype.raider/cache
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.skype.raider
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.android.calendar/files
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.android.calendar
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.magazines/cache
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.magazines/files
384K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.magazines
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.videos/files/Movies
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.videos/files
384K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.videos
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.maps/files
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.maps
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.piriform.ccleaner/files
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.piriform.ccleaner
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.cleanmaster.mguard/files
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.cleanmaster.mguard/cache
384K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.cleanmaster.mguard
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.sec.android.gallery3d/cache
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.sec.android.gallery3d
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.gms/files
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.gms
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/org.videolan.vlc/cache
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/org.videolan.vlc/files
384K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/org.videolan.vlc
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files/olpv3/v5/25/r12
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files/olpv3/v5/25/r11
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files/olpv3/v5/25/r13
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files/olpv3/v5/25/r15
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files/olpv3/v5/25/r16
768K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files/olpv3/v5/25
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files/olpv3/v5/02/r11
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files/olpv3/v5/02/r13
384K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files/olpv3/v5/02
1,2M    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files/olpv3/v5
1,4M    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files/olpv3
1,5M    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate/files
1,6M    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.apps.translate
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.microsoft.skydrive/cache
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.microsoft.skydrive
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.music/files
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.music/cache
512K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.google.android.music
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.facebook.katana/cache
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.facebook.katana/files
384K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.facebook.katana
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/ch.threema.app/files
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/ch.threema.app
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.samsung.android.coreapps/cache
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.samsung.android.coreapps
128K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.homeysoft.nexususb.importer/files/Download
256K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.homeysoft.nexususb.importer/files
384K    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data/com.homeysoft.nexususb.importer
7,4M    ./.Trashes/502/Android/data
7,5M    ./.Trashes/502/Android
256K    ./.Trashes/502/DCIM/MISC
512K    ./.Trashes/502/DCIM/106GOPRO
1,0M    ./.Trashes/502/DCIM
128K    ./.Trashes/502/LOST.DIR
512K    ./.Trashes/502/MISC
 43G    ./.Trashes/502
 43G    ./.Trashes
128K    ./.android_secure
 43G    .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I saved all my data and deleted ALL files using right click and delete.

There is no "delete" item in Finder contextual menus.

There is a "move to Trash" item, which moves a file to the Trash. You still need to empty the Trash to actually delete the file and free up storage.

To empty the Trash, right-click on the Trash icon in the Dock and select "Empty Trash".

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you delete files, they are just moved to hidden Trash folder.

In this case you need to empty the Trash Bin. Then the files will be deleted permanently.

Also you need to know, that even then files are able to be restored, because only information in filesystem on SD card is knowing that the files are deleted, but their content is still on the card. You need a wipe software to be sure that you delete the content of the files - in case you want to sell/give away the SD card.